# Using options to profit from underlying stock and warrants

Tags: hedging, option-strategies, warrants

I'm a suffering shareholder and have underlying stock and  warrants (3 years remaining) and want to know how to profit from them using a option or hedge strategy. 
The current stock price is 30% below my warrant strike price. I am long-term bullish on the stock and I feel the stock will rebound this year as well.  There is no borrow for the stock.  There also isnt a great amount of trading activity on the options.
Thank you! 
KK

Comment: What do you think the stock price will do in the next 3 - 6 - 9 months?